# How do I remove sudo from my server without breaking everything?

Tags: sudo

I am creating a test server VM, and I would like to delete the `sudo` executable by deleting it via apt.

I know the root password, so that is not a downside.

Is there any problem about removing `sudo` from a system? I do not care about losing the capability to run commands with `sudo`. I practically live as the root user.

Programs Needed:

- Apache2
- MySQL
- FTP

Comment: You may just try it, create snapshot for VM then rename `sudo` (as root run `mv /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/sudo.backup`). Also you may verify other tools depend on it `apt-cache -i rdepends sudo`

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @MosheKatz Keep users out of the root shell.

Comment: The proper way to do that would just be to disallow access in the sudoers file (or just don't put them in the `admin` or `sudo` groups and they wont have sudo access to begin with).

Comment: @MosheKatz But I want to DELETE sudo!

Comment: "I live as the root user". This is bad practice. Don't do it. `sudo` has uses beyond "switch to UID 0".